# Pro-rata Excel Spreadsheet Calculator Needed for House-share Bill Spliting

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm very new to excel, and I'm hoping someone could provide the spreadsheet formula which will calculate the below pro rata for each person:

I require a spreadsheet to calculate the total bill amount ($336.70) split between six people. I'm using day rates between a bill period of 174 days. Some people haven't been living with me for the entire 174 day bill period and I'm needing to calculate the following:

How much the following six people living in the house-share owe:

- Person 1: Pro rata 174 days of the house's total owing bill amount
  ($336.70) over the 174 day bill period
- Person 2: Pro rata 174 days of the house's total owing bill amount ($336.70) over the 174 day bill period
- Person 3: Pro rata 162 days of the house's total owing bill amount
  ($336.70) over the 174 day bill period
- Person 4: Pro rata 143 days of the house's total owing bill amount ($336.70) over the 174 day bill period
- Person 5: Pro rata 74 days of the house's total owing bill amount ($336.70) over the 174 day bill period
- Person 6: Pro rata 41 days of the house's total owing bill amount
  ($336.70) over the 174 day bill period

Can anyone please assist?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Divide total amount owed by number of days to give amount per day, then multiply by the number of days for each person...

Comment: We're here to help you fix existing formulas that aren't working, but not to write new formulas from scratch. You should have a go yourself, post your work, and ask for help to fix them.

Comment: @SolarMike that methodology isn't correct for this case.

336.70 / 174 = $1.935 day rate. So with your methodology; Person 1 owes $336.69, which isn't correct (that's the whole bill amount). I'm trying to split this between six different people. So I thought it should be: 336.70 / 174 / 6 = 0.33cents per day, per person. But 174 * 0.33 = $57.42 - this also isn't correct as if I do this for each of the six people, the total amount between all individuals equates to ~ $250 and not the total bill owing sum of $336.70.. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @Jase see my answer, if it helps you then accept the answer with the check or tick. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, try this:

[image]

Total days is the sum of all the days from each person, NOT just the time period.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Excel, it's a lot of fun if you play around with it. What you're looking for isn't a single formula so much as it is a layout. In the spreadsheet I used to solve the problem I put names in column A and days in column B.

Person 1            174

Person 2          174

Person 3    162

Person 4    143

Person 5    74

Person 6    41

In column C I put the follow
ing formula:

=B1/SUM(B:B)*336.7

Drag that down and it should solve the problem nicely. One thing I would do, however, is put the 336.7 in another cell and have the formula reference the cell. That way you can easily change the bill amount without mucking around in the formula.

If you were to put it in D1 use this formula:
=B1/SUM(B:B)*$D$1

The dollar signs lock the cell reference so it won't change when you drag it down.